# edit role display name and label name without plugins

Tags: functions, user-roles

I'am creating WordPress function for editing role name

```
function change_role_name($role_name, $new_role_name, $display_name) {
    global $wp_roles;

    if ( ! isset( $wp_roles ) )
        $wp_roles = new WP_Roles();

    $role =& get_role($role_name);

    $wp_roles->roles[$role]['name'] = $new_role_name; //not working for sa
    $wp_roles->role_names[$role] = $display_name;           
}
```

problem here it don't change the role label name

Comment: http://www.garyc40.com/2010/04/ultimate-guide-to-roles-and-capabilities/#add-roles

Answer (score 3):

Those names are stored in the option `wp_user_roles` in the database table `wp_options`.

So, the following will change the name of the `subscriber` role:

```
$val = get_option( 'wp_user_roles' );
$val['subscriber']['name'] = 'PeDeBoi';
update_option( 'wp_user_roles', $val );
```

<sup>Apparently, this is harmless, but *caveat emptor*...</sup>

In your code, `$wp_roles->roles[$role]['name'] = $new_role_name;` doesn't work because it should be:

```
$wp_roles->roles[$role_name]['name'] = $new_role_name;
```

And `$display_name` doesn't make much sense.

Comment: Thank's for this information, it helped me out!
I'll just add the option is not really `wp_user_roles` but it seems to be `{$wpdb->prefix}user_roles` for me